# Issue getting ANSICON working on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

Tags: cmd, cucumber, jruby, ansicon

I have been trying to get 1.50 or 1.40 ANSICON (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) working and have looked at sooooo many pages telling about how to install this:
http://blog.mmediasys.com/2010/11/24/we-all-love-colors/
http://carol-nichols.com/2011/03/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/

etc....

So, I have my AutoRun set to "C:\usr\bin\ansi140\x64\ansicon.exe" -p and I also testing 150 but there was zero change.

My entire team has this working with no issues but I cannot get this to work.. I still get the garbled junk on the command prompt:

```
  Scenario: Residential caller chooses to hear payment locations closest to home and there are 3 locations available which are in a 25 miles radius.?[90m #
 features\payment_locations.feature:5?[0m
    ?[32mGiven the call flow is '?[32m?[1mDivisional?[0m?[0m?[32m'?[90m
                          # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:5?[0m?[0m
    ?[32mAnd the ani is '?[32m?[1m6101234572?[0m?[0m?[32m'?[90m
                          # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:9?[0m?[0m
    ?[32mAnd the dnis is '?[32m?[1m9?[0m?[0m?[32m'?[90m
                          # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:13?[0m?[0m
    ?[31mWhen the call is started?[90m
    # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:17?[0m?[0m
?[31m      Connection refused - Connection refused (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)?[0m
?[31m      org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:121:in `initialize'?[0m
?[31m      org/jruby/RubyIO.java:864:in `new'?[0m
?[31m      org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:147:in `open'?[0m
?[31m      c:/usr/bin/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'?[0m
?[31m      org/jruby/ext/Timeout.java:79:in `timeout'?[0m
?[31m      c:/usr/bin/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'?[0m
?[31m      c:/usr/bin/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'?[0m
?[31m      c:/usr/bin/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:548:in `start'?[0m
?[31m      org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2100:in `send'?[0m
?[31m      ./features/support/request_helper.rb:12:in `request'?[0m
?[31m      ./features/support/request_helper.rb:4:in `get'?[0m
?[31m      ./features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:22:in `(root)':in `/^the call is started$/'?[0m
?[31m      features\payment_locations.feature:9:in `When the call is started'?[0m
```

Can anyone PLEASE help me try to understand why I am having this issue when the rest of my team with the same laptops are not having this issue?

EDIT from first comment:

I tried what you asked and ende dup with this tab setting:

```
    <tab title="ANSICON" icon="linux.ico" use_default_icon="0">
        <console shell="C:\usr\bin\ansi150\x64\ansicon.exe" init_dir="C:\usr\git_workspaces\d2" run_as_user="0" user=""/>
        <cursor style="0" r="255" g="255" b="255"/>
        <background type="0" r="0" g="0" b="0">
            <image file="" relative="0" extend="0" position="0">
                <tint opacity="0" r="0" g="0" b="0"/>
            </image>
        </background>
    </tab>
```

But the issue still persists

```
    ?[0m  ?[36m    <catch event="error">
    ?[0m  ?[36m        <submit next="/d2/exception/handleVoiceBrowserError.vxml" namelist="_event _message" />
    ?[0m  ?[36m    </catch>
    ?[0m  ?[36m
          ?[36m</vxml>?[0m
        ?[32mThen play the payment locations?[90m
                                                          # features/step_definitions/billing_steps.rb:360?[0m?[0m
        ?[32mThen caller hangs up the phone?[90m
                                                          # features/step_definitions/goodbye_steps.rb:1?[0m?[0m

    1 scenario (?[32m1 passed?[0m)
    32 steps (?[32m32 passed?[0m)
    0m10.302s
```

I also seem to have the term-ansicolor gem so this should be working

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

atoulme-Antwrap (0.7.1 java)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
builder (2.1.2)
buildr (1.4.6 java)
buildr-xivr (0.0.6, 0.0.4)
bundler (1.0.20)
crack (0.1.8)
cucumber (1.0.0, 0.10.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
gherkin (2.4.21 java, 2.4.16 java, 2.3.8 java)
highline (1.5.1)
hoe (2.3.3)
hpricot (0.8.3 java)
httparty (0.7.8, 0.7.7)
jruby-openssl (0.7.5, 0.7.4)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.6.5 java, 1.5.4 java, 1.5.1 java)
json_pure (1.4.3)
mechanize (1.0.0)
minitar (0.5.3)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.4)
net-ssh (2.0.23)
nokogiri (1.5.0 java, 1.5.0.beta.4 java)
rake (0.8.7)
rspec (2.1.0, 1.3.2)
rspec-core (2.1.0)
rspec-expectations (2.1.0)
rspec-mocks (2.1.0)
rubyforge (2.0.3)
rubygems-update (1.8.10)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sources (0.0.1)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7, 1.0.6, 1.0.5)
xml-simple (1.0.12)
```

but it is not. Neither on Cygwin nor CMD.
The plot thickens

Comment: Same issues here, and unfortunately @Elvans answer doesn't work for me either. hope you find a resolution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) worked. Additionally, you may want to check out [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for an excellent multi-tabbed console.

1. Extract ansi152/x64 into `<console-install-dir>`, say `C:\Apps\Console`
2. Configure console to run with different shells, ie. powershell, cmd, gitbash
3. Run `ansicon -i` from `<console-install-dir>`, in console.

PS. You may need to add `console-install-dir` into your `$env:path`.

Answer (score 2):

To fix ansicon installation,

1. Grab [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), extract, to a folder, mine `C:\Applications\`.
2. Extract files from `ansi150.zip\x64`, use 64-bit binaries, place it in a same folder with Console2.
3. Open `C:\Applications\Console2\Console.exe`.
4. From Console2 menu open `File > Edit > Settings > Tabs`, fill in `Shell` with `C:\Applications\Console2\ansicon.exe`, or browse to it. Click Ok.
5. To apply changes reopen a Console2 tab.

My setup is Console-2.00b148-Beta_64bit.zip and ansi150.zip on Win 7 64-bit (without editing AutoRun registry).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem myself and I am finally seeing colored output.
I followed these steps:

1. Download "https://github.com/downloads/adoxa/ansicon/ansi150.zip"
2. Copy the files under the "x64" directory to somewhere in your path.

   For example, you can copy them to "c:\windows\system32".
3. Download "https://github.com/downloads/adoxa/ansicon/ansi6432.zip"
4. Copy the files under the "x64" directory to the same location you used in step #2.

   This should overwrite ANSI32.DLL and ansicon.exe
5. Install ansicon by typing "ansicon -I" at a command prompt

You should now see colored output.

Make sure to enable logging by setting the environment variable ANSICON_LOG:

set ANSICON_LOG=3

This should log output to %TEMP%\ansicon.log (Usually "c:\temp\ansicon.log")

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that we need to set this:

> set ANSICON_EXC=nvd3d9wrap.dll

(add it to a ansicon.bat file, or set an environment variable). Works like a champ with win64x pro, ansicon164